# How to declare a type which describe key and corresponding value type of some object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to make the compiler check the type of value in this case?

```
type SomeType = {
  foo: string[];
  bar: number | null;
};

type SomeTypeChanges<K extends keyof SomeType = keyof SomeType> = {
  key: K;
  value: SomeType[K]
};

declare function baz(changes: SomeTypeChanges);

// must be an error in both cases
baz({key: "foo", value: 1}); // type of value must be string[]
baz({key: "bar", value: ["a", "b"]}) // type of value must be number | null
```

actually, the situation is more difficult
I export this stuff from external library:

```
export interface MyEvent<Payload> {
  (payload: Payload): Payload;
}
export declare function createEvent<E = void>(eventName?: string): MyEvent<E>;
```

and trying to use is it like this:

```
const myEvent = createEvent<SomeTypeChanges<keyof SomeType>>();
myEvent({ key: "foo", value: 1 });
                      ^^^^^
```

So I cant add the type parameters to the function

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the type parameters to the function. The function is the vehicle that causes inference to occur at call site. Just because the type is generic does not mean any inference will happen, and since you have a default for `K` that will be used and you will get no error.

This works as you expect it to:

```
type SomeType = {
  foo: string[];
  bar: number | null;
};

type SomeTypeChanges<K extends keyof SomeType> = {
  key: K;
  value: SomeType[K]
};

declare function baz<K extends keyof SomeType>(changes: SomeTypeChanges<K>);

// must be an error in both cases
baz({key: "foo", value: 1}); // err
baz({key: "bar", value: ["a", "b"]}) // err
```

Comment: @abdurahmanus I can only post solutions to code you show, post a fuller example and we can see what can be done